# how to know which side of a peranant magnet is which?

Tags: magnetic-fields

How to determin which side of a magnet is North and Wich side is South? It is my first time asking so I don't know if it is the right place to ask.

Comment: Have you tried a compass?

Comment: https://www.kjmagnetics.com/blog.asp?p=which-pole-is-north

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The poles do have some determinable features.

If you're on earth, the north end of a magnet will point towards the North Pole. The south end of a magnet will point towards the South Pole.

By noting that the sun rises in the east and sets in the west, you can determine the north and south poles of earth. Thus, if you make an appropriate compass, you can compactly describe the above observations. You could also just use a phone compass, gps etc. It's also been suggested that hanging the magnet from a string could work.

So, to determine which side is which on a permanent magnet, hold a side of it up against a compass. If the end you hold out attracts the arrow of the compass, the end is the south side, and vice versa.

It's important to note that the north and south poles of earth actually sit off kilter compared to the "true" north and south poles. This means, that most, but not all places, will be conducive to this method. [Here's](http://rimstar.org/renewnrg/finding_true_south_pole.htm) a reference describing some of the basics concerning the geography based on Earth's poles.

Comment: If you don't have a compass (they're rare in these days of GPS...) you can hang a bar magnet from a string. The end that swings north is the south pole. A thin fishing line would be better than a string, as a string may tend to untwist, and counteract the earth's magnetism. Of course, this is hard to do with a fridge magnet or other magnet shapes.

Comment: @hdhondt that's a good idea too. Although, know that I think about it most phones have a compass ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is a fundamental problem.

If you are not on Earth (or on Earth eons ago when the poles were reversed) the suggested methods won't work. I could tell you to make a battery by sticking zinc and copper electrodes into a lemon, and then wind a coil in a certain sense to make an electromagnet.

But I cannot describe that sense in words. I could tell you to use the left hand rule to wind the coil, but then I have to explain in words the difference between left and right. I could send a digital image to your planet, but how would you know whether you are viewing it mirror-image?